# wanting different formatting in webstorm then I'm getting (JavaScript)

Tags: resharper, webstorm

I'm getting this by default:

```
a: {
  xx: '1'
},
{
  xx: '2'
}
```

and I want

```
a: {
  xx: '1'
},{
  xx: '2'
}
```

I can't find the option.  Am I crazy for wanting that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option, please vote for [WEB-7226](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7226)

Comment: is adding a comment the only way to vote?  seems like it was asked for 15 months ago. very sad this was not considered important since it is a very common style many of us use.  I'm doing video training and I will be slammed for bad formatting without it and people will see it is webstorm I'm using for my formatting.

Comment: You need to press thumbs up button to vote. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23368682-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications